# Limiting the data taking from sql database

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to limit the data that'll taken from the sql database. Currently this code gets all data that the table has. I want to limit it to 10. How can i do it?

`Code: https://pastebin.com/RuYbRhai`

Comment: can you be more specific with the section of code you use to retrieve the data from the database? One thing that pops to mind is within a SQL Query you can use LIMIT for the amount of records you will retrieve, is this what you mean?

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (i.e. Postgres, Oracle, MySql)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question** and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

Add "LIMIT 10" at the end of your SQL statement.